# DataTable not sorting numeric set of data

Tags: sorting, datatables

[image]

Sorting of numbers under unique column is not proper, it is sorting numbers perfectly when there are same no of digits but when there comes different no digits sorting is not proper (sorting as a string).

```
$('.table').dataTable({ 
   "searching": false 
}); 

$($('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper .row')[0]).hide();
```

Comment: It would be real nice to see how you initialise the dataTable **in code**. A picture can be helpful for understanding the problem, not nessecarily helpful to solve the problem, since the problem is code based :)

Comment: eventsTable = $('.table').dataTable({
    "searching": false
  });      
  $($('#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper .row')[0]).hide();
I am using the default configuration 
}

Comment: share your data table code as @davidkonrad mentioned . It will be helpful to find the root cause .